# Unable to edit the 1Homepage

Tags: customization, homepage

My homepage is physically viewable when the site loads but the "homepage page" for it (containing any design elements) can't be found when I go to the dashboard and select all pages. I am using an active child theme.

Since the page is visible, its active page must exist somewhere. When I am on the live page and click inspect I don't see the identity of the source page.  I am wanting to be able to modify the presentation of the visible live page but can't figure out how to edit it without having a page to work with. As of late, I created a separate page called "homepage" but while it refers back to the live visible page, it does not offer any eleme to like blocks, menus or widgets that were used to create the page.

I looked at the homepage customizer and it only recognizes things like background etc, but not blocks or widgets.  Much of the visible page uses widgets for content.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not require a frontpage be created in the backend: a theme with a `front-page.php` file can be completely hard-coded and not depend on blocks or widgets. Check your parent and child themes for a `front-page.php`.